# Why are statefull and stateless class are abstract classes in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I was told that to make use of a class we create it's object but in flutter we extend our class with stateless or statefull widgets without creating objects of it, now you may say we can't create objects out of abstract class but what I'm asking is how is it working and why did they use abstract class at first place.

Comment: If `StatefulWidget` and `StatelessWidget` weren't abstract, then you could instantiate them directly without a subclass.  What would you do with them?  What would they do?  Classes are `abstract` when they want to require that subclasses define and implement behaviors.

Comment: to use a class we make it's object but in flutter we are not creating objects of statefull or stateless classes but still it's working, i want to know how . @jamesdlin

Comment: Huh?  You construct widget instances that *derive* from the `StatefulWidget` and `StatelessWidget` abstract base classes.

Answer (score 1):

For the [abstract](https://dart.dev/samples#interfaces-and-abstract-classes)

> Dart has no interface keyword. Instead, all classes implicitly define an interface. Therefore, you can implement any class.

So we have two general way to use this abstract class. One is  by `implements` where we need to override all methods and another one `extend` the class.

An example code

```dart
abstract class A {
  final int data = 1;
}

class B implements A {
  @override
  int get data => 2;
}

class C extends A {}

void main(List<String> args) {
  final itemB = B();
  print(itemB.data); // print 2
  final itemC = C();
  print(itemC.data); // print 1
}
```

As you can see, you are not force to override and initialize value on extends because its extends duty to get parent behavior.

While flutter is a framework, and framework means

> a software framework is an abstraction in which software, **providing generic functionality, can be selectively changed by additional user-written code, thus providing application-specific software**.... more on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_framework)

*So Why we extends `StatelessWidget` and `StatefulWidget`,* Because we are using a flutter framework, and we don't want to create things from scratch, we just use and override provided functionality based on our need.

This is a taught concept for me to describe, but tried my best to simplify it. Feel free to update the answer if you find any mistake.

Comment: to use a class we make it's object but in flutter we are not creating objects of statefull or stateless classes but still it's working, i want to know how @Yeasin Sheikh

Comment: We are creating object and directly assigning it without assigning on variable.  While we are doing `runApp(MyApp())`, here we are creating an `MyApp` object. You can check more about OOP.